# Regex issue with SingleLine Option and \n before end of string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to match a certain end of a file, where the "certain end of the file" could go over multiple lines.

My regex looks like follows:

```
"\s\w$"
```

What I want to do: Find all files that end with a whitespace character, followed by a "human readable character" at the very end of the file.

```
Regex.IsMatch("arbitrarytext a\n",@"\s\w$")
```

Problem is it matches the following string also:

```
"arbitrarytext a\n"
```

I also tried RegexOptions.SingleLine - although this should only change the matching behavior of a dot ".".

How can I rewrite my regex that it still fulfills my needs but does not match the example given above.

Secondly I'm also interested in an explanation why it matches the example at all.

Using: .Net 3.5 SP1 if that is of interest.

Comment: You should format your code better. As it is written \n is literally a slash followed by n not a newline. In any case your original regex is correct. I don't know where your problem is, unless you want to match sequences of `\n` .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `$` matches at the end of the string *before* the final newline character (if there is one). Unless you use `RegexOptions.Multiline`, `$` means the same as `\Z`.

Use `\z` instead:

```
Regex.IsMatch("arbitrarytext a\n",@"\s\w\z")
```

will fail.

See also this [tutorial about anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), specifically the section "Strings Ending with a Line Break".

A short overview:

```
Symbol  means...                                       if multiline mode is...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
^       Start of string                                off (default*)   
^       Start of current line                          on               
\A      Start of string                                irrelevant       
$       End of string, before final newline, if any    off              
$       End of current line, before newline, if any    on               
\Z      End of string, before final newline, if any    irrelevant       
\z      End of string                                  irrelevant       

*: In Ruby, multiline mode is always on. Use \A or \Z to get ^ or $ behavior.
```

Comment: From MSDN documentation: By default, $ matches only the end of the input string. If you specify the RegexOptions.Multiline option, it matches either the newline character (\n) or the end of the input string.

Comment: Strings ending in a line break are the exception to that rule you quoted. I have added a link that explains this behavior.